# Why code version controller does not work in erlang?

Tags: sockets, erlang

I Wrote this module for a simple server program that receives a request and send a response to client. It works fine But when if recompile this module while a client connected, the client disconnects and if i reconnect client to this server and send a request, there is no response. Is there any idea?!

Here is my module:

```
-module(controller).
-export([start/1, loop/1, response/2]).

-include_lib("types.hrl").

-define(END_CHAR, "$").


-spec start(Port) -> no_return() when
    Port :: char().

-spec loop(Listen) -> no_return() when
    Listen :: port().

-spec handler(Socket) -> no_return() when
    Socket :: port().

-spec response(HandlerPID, Data) -> {send_msg, Msg} when
    HandlerPID :: pid(),
    Data :: string(),
    Msg :: response().



start(Port) ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, once}]),
    spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Listen]).


loop(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Listen]),
    handler(Socket).



handler(Socket) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            %io:format("recv ~p~n", [Data]),
            spawn(?MODULE, response, [self(), Data]),
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
            handler(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            %io:format("disconnected~n", []),
            gen_tcp:close(Socket);

        {send_msg, Msg} ->
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Msg])) ++ ?END_CHAR),
            handler(Socket)
    end.


response(PID, Data) ->
    [Req|Args] = string:tokens(Data, ?END_CHAR),
    {ReqPID, ReqRef} = spawn_monitor(view, request, [list_to_atom(Req), self(), Args]),
    receive
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {function_clause, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, invalid_request};
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {{case_clause, _}, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, bad_args};
        {'DOWN', ReqRef, process, ReqPID, {{badmatch, _}, _}} -> PID ! {send_msg, bad_args};
        Resp -> PID ! {send_msg, Resp}
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note

```
    {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
        %io:format("disconnected~n", []),
        gen_tcp:close(Socket);
```

in `handler`. It doesn't call `handler` again, it just returns and so the server process stops.

Your `loop` function name is also misleading, `handler` is the actual loop.

Comment: I call hander again after it receives a request or response!

Comment: But not when the client disconnects. And as you say, "if recompile this module while a client connected, **the client disconnects** and if i reconnect client to this server and send a request, there is no response". You need to listen for a new client.

Comment: Alternately, this may be a good time to start learning about OTP: convert your server to a `gen_server` and put it under a `supervisor` which will restart it automatically.

Comment: Then include updated code in the question, it presumably doesn't work for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at [Ranch](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/ranch/1.1/guide/) - A socket acceptor pool for the TCP connections.